# Database of searches within Pinterest (or other social networks)

Tags: data-request, social-media, search-engine

I want to see what people are searching the most within [Pinterest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinterest).

It would be like an equivalent of the Google Keyword Research tool, but for Pinterest.

Data for similar/other social networks is OK too.

Comment: As I know, there isn't a tool like this one. But maybe you will find a few related statistics in this paper http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~sbakhshi/gilbert.chi13.pinterest.pdf

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris thanks page 7-8 helped get an idea of how people are searching. Assuming pinterest wants to hold on to the specific data tight.